# android in-app-billing not getting response in 2.1

Tags: android

I downloaded sample `in-app-billing` application and I tried to run that application on devices
its working fine for devices with `android OS version 2.2`.
but I am getting problem with  devices having `OS version 2.1`.

Actually  I am able to connect to market server and I am receiving response saying that `request sent to server` ,but I am not getting response about purchase state (ie whether the purchase is success or not).
we are getting this problem with `android OS 2.1` devices,for `OS 2.2` its working fine.(i tested in devices with `OS 2.1` and `2.2` only)

Answer (score 2):

From developer pages: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

System requirements for subscriptions

In-app purchases of subscriptions are supported only on devices that meet these minimum requirements:

Must run Android 2.2 or higher
Google Play Store app, version 3.5 or higher, must be installed
Google Play 3.5 and later versions include support for the In-app Billing v2 API or higher, which is needed to support handling of subscription products.